# Quip LiveApp: no callback from refreshToken on error

Tags: liveapps, quip

I have a bit of code that is using OAuth2 to talk to Salesforce.
If I call quip.app.refreshToken and there is an error from Salesforce then the it never gets a callback.

So the code is like this

```
quip.apps.auth('salesforce').refreshToken().then(
    response => this.error('Refresh succeeded')
).catch(
    e => this.error('Refresh failed')
);
```

and I can see in the console that Salesforce is returning
    {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"token validity expired"}

However neither is the response or catch being called in the code.  This implies that if the code is attempting to 'retry' a bit of code after refresh that it's basically left in limbo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quip platform was updated yesterday and have fixed this issue.